# Activtiy1 to Adaper to Activity2 ，and how to use the Activity1 data in Activtiy2

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I have two Activies, named `Activtiy1` and `Activity2`, and one `Adapter`.
`Activity1` use the adapter, and in the adapter, I use intent to jump to `Activiy2`.
My problem is that `Activity2` wants to use the data from `Activiy1`, but I have no simple way to come through.
I want a simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: what kind of data object(String, int, array) are you trying to intent ?

Comment: We dont see your code but one way is to make that data `public static` and access it

Comment: Have you try to use Intent putExtra() ?

Comment: You can declare object as a global variable using Singleton pattern. for more details follow the link https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218

Comment: i am  lazy to use Intent putExtra().

Comment: Please post your code. From where this problem came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

1. When creating an intent, put the data in a bundle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html, and add it to the intent.
2. Take a look at the singleton design pattern. Create the object in one activity and it will be accessibly to the other activity.
3. If all your data are primitive types, you can use intent.putExtra(..,..);

Answer (score 0):

In activity-1 start activity-2

```
       Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
         i.putExtra("Key","your data");
        StartActivity(i);
```

and in second activity get data from first activity

```
          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.xml);

             String data = getIntent.getExtra("key");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is data"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
```